# How to fix ‘Exec format error’ in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fortran, apple-m1

I am trying to download intel Fortran and when the files were extracted they  were soon been removed:

Extract 1_HPCKit_p_2023.2.0.49440_offline completed!
/home/tanyang/1_HPCKit_P_2023.2.0.49440_offline/install.sh: 34: /home/tanyang/1_
HPCKit_P_2023.2.0.49440_offline/bootstrapper: Exec format error
Remove extracted files: /home/anyang/_HPCKit_p_2023.2.0.49440_offline.

I’m using Ubuntu 22.04 on apple virtualization .

I don’t know how to fix it. Can anyone help me fix it? Thanks a lot!

Hope someone can save me from this problem!Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not post text as screenshots, copy/paste the text instead. We also need more details: which machine/OS are you using, and which version of Intel Fortran have you downloaded? You have set a "linux" tag, but "Apple" appears in your screenshot. Do not post the additionnal details as a comment, please edit your question instead.

Comment: Has your Mac an Intel CPU (x86) or Apple Silicon ARM CPU (M1/M2)? I'm pretty sure that the Intel Fortran compiler is available only for the Intel CPUs.

Comment: oh my mac is M1 maybe that's why thank u so much！

Comment: So I wonder if there’s a way to run intel Fortran on my visual machine?

Comment: You would need a full x86 emulator, not just a virtual machine. And still, the compiler would produce x86 binaries, which would have to be emulated. In principle, the macOS built-in Rosetta 2 can transcode x86 binaries to ARM instructions on the fly, but it's probably not that easy to set up Intel Fortran to work with Rosetta 2... Unless you really want to work with the Intel compilers, you should consider alternatives, so as gfortran.

Comment: ok thanks a lot！I’m running a code which can only be compiled by ifort.

Comment: Fortran is a very portable language. If a code can only be compiled by ifort, it is likely incorrect or at least problematic and should be fixed. You are welcome to ask questions how to fix your code for compilation with other compilers. The usual instructions [ask] would apply.

Comment: It is very likely than your fortran source code is compilable with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. Install it using the `apt install gfortran gcc` command as root